# Capturing all mouse event in a container

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, fxml

I am refactoring a JavaFX class file to a Controller class and a FXML file.  In the old JavaFX class I had to create a safety net for all mouse events by putting a rectangle at the bottom z layer so that mouse events that happen while the mouse was not on a node in the scene the code would still get all mouse events.  Is there a better way in FXML?

Comment: There's basically no difference at all in the functionality you get: FXML is just a different (perhaps more convenient) way to specify the objects that should be created and the properties that should be set on them. It's not at all clear why you would want to place a rectangle at the bottom layer to handle mouse events anyway: why not just register the same mouse listener with the container itself?

Comment: Events travel down and up the scene graph tree ([see *1 Processing Events*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD)). Manually adding a "safety net" shouldn't be necessary, (see James_D's comment)...

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an event handler to the scene itself:

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
    System.out.println(event);
});
```